# What is a similect?

Tags: terminology, dialects

I'm looking for attested examples of similects in action. The term is relatively new for me. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
Etymology

Coined by Anna Mauranen in a 2012 paper, from similar +‎ -lect, modelled
on dialect, etc. 

Noun

similect (plural similects) (linguistics) A variety of a language 
spoken by people who have a different first language, with features
transferred from the first language in parallel by individual speakers
rather than by a cohesive group.
```

Source: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/similect

Comment: I've never heard the term either. Guess its an umbrella term for an undefined measure of distance and thus similarity. A single person can have a similect if they move from Berlin to Hamburg and start speaking with a Platt affection, imperfectly, if you want to count those dialects as different languages; Same for all High German learned second by speakers of dialect. More placative perhaps the English spoken by bilangual Africans from all over the place with different Mother tongues who learn a kind of English as a second language. Might want to exclude creoles from the definition though